# select from multi-dimensional arrays based on a given condition

Tags: pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, numpy-ndarray

There is an ndarray `data` with shape, e.g., `(5, 10, 2)`; and other two lists, `x1` and `x2`. Both of size `10`. I want select  subset from `data` based on the following conditions,

```
Across the second dimension
 If     x1[i]<= data[j, i,0] <=x2[i], then we will select data[j, i,:]
```

I tried `selected = data[x1<=data[:,:,0]<=x2]`. It does not work. I am not clear what's the efficient (or vectorized) way to implement this condition-based selection.

Comment: How do you intend to perform the comparison? Elementwise? Is that the intended behaviour? You should give a MRE with expected output.

Comment: When you say select what do you mean? Please include an input and an output to help us understand your problem.

Comment: Don't write **It does not work**.  Show the error or what is wrong with it.  But I'll make a guess - `x1<=x<=x2` only works with scalars.  The double sided test does not work with numpy arrays.  You'll have to split it into 2 tests, and logically combine them.  You may have to first create a working - non-vectorized - solution, before worrying about efficiency.  A [mcve] may help, since any good answer will have to show that it is working.

Comment: Are you iterating through each `j` between 0 and 4 inclusive? I'm assuming you're iterating through each `i` between 0 and 9 inclusive. For the 3rd dimension, do you only care about index 0 (as suggested by `data[:, :, 0]` or do you want to iterate through everything in that dimension as well? Please post example `data`, `x1` and `x2` as well as expected output. And perhaps try a `for` loop before you try vectorizing, just so we have a better idea of what you want.

Comment: @David, yeah, I should have clarified with more detail. I need element wise comparison. both x1 and x2 are list or one dimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below selects all values in `data` where the third dimension is 0 (i.e. each value has some index `data[i, j, 0]` and where the value is <= than the corresponding `x2` and >= than the corresponding `x1`:

```
idx = np.where(np.logical_and(data[:, :, 0] >= np.array(x1), data[:, :, 0] <= np.array(x2)))

# data[idx] contains the full rows of length 2 rather than just the 0th column, so we need to select the 0th column.
selected = data[idx][:, 0]
```

The code assumes that `x1` and `x2` are lists with lengths equal to the size of `data`'s second dimension (in this case, 10). Note that the code only returns the values, not the indices of the values.

Let me know if you have any questions.